Circular Dependency on Power BI, when Couple Measure depends on each other
I have a problem when I create measure
here code I created
[init value]=1000000

Compensation = 

var a = CALCULATE([Remaining Credit], PREVIOUSMONTH(FYCalendar[Date]))

return IF(a=BLANK(), [init value], a)

Remaining Credit = 

[Compensation]+[Current Credit]


What is Current Credit? Share what your data table looks like.

You are creating measure Compensation and referring the measure Remaining Credit in it.
While creating measure Remaining Credit, you again referring Compensation in it.
So your first measure has dependency on second and Second one has dependency on the first one and here you are getting the error. This is called Circular Dependency. You can search in google for the key word "Circular Dependency" and you will get lot of explanation on it.
